# Is $\cos(x+y)=e^x$ an implicit function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have tried separating the variables so as to find the answer. I had used the $\cos^{-1}(x)$ on both the sides and hence succeeded. However the answer given is that it is implicit. I searched on the internet and had got some mixed answers...Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For any given real $x$, ___if___ a solution $y_0$ exists for $y$, then $\hat{y}_0 = -y-2x$ is another solution between cosine is an even function. Furthermore, because cosine is periodic, we have solutions $y_n = n\cdot 2\pi\cdot y_0$ and $\hat{y}_n = n\cdot 2\pi\cdot \hat{y}_0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ as well. So if we plot the solutions, I guess we will have superposed two infinite families of "parallel" curves stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Inverse trig functions are multivalued, and so is your function $y(x)$. Depending on the domain you work with, you may need to specify the particular branch to properly define the function

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(x+y)=e^x$$
is an implicit equation, which can be made explicit as
$$y=\arccos \left(e^x\right)-x$$

Note: Some, however, consider any equation that can be made explicit, not implicit. But, many of the seemingly implicit functions can be made explicit with varying degrees of efforts so it's pretty subjective.

Comment: but $y$ is real only for $x \le 0$ ..

Comment: @GCab therefore...?

Comment: Also the implicit function is defined for $x\le0$

Comment: That's not the only solution for $y$. See the comments below the question.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat: mine was nothing else than a note.

Comment: @HansLundmark yep I’m aware of that. I just didn’t go into it coz the op isn’t solving it anyway.